# matches method taking a lot of time to execute in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Am using regular expression called glob i.e., *.

example:

```
String str="this is *";

String str1="this is regular Expression";
```

If we call matches on these strings they should be equal.

Please check the below code which is taking a lot of time for executions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String value="NO OTHER GERM CELL COMPONENT. TUMOR DIMENSIONS: **X**X** CM. TUMOR FOCALITY: FOCAL MULTIFOCAL INTRA-TUBULAR GERM CELL NEOPLASIA (ITGN): PRESENT ABSENT SCATTERED SYNCTOIOTROPHOBLASTIC GIANT CELLS PRESENT/NO SCATTERED SYNCYTIOTROPHOBLASTIC GIANT CELLS PRESENT RETE TESTIS INVOLVEMENT BY INVASIVE TUMOR: PRESENT ABSENT EXTENSION BEYOND TUNICA ALBUGINEA: PRESENT ABSENT ANGIOLYMPHATIC INVASION : PRESENT ABSENT SPERMATIC CORD MARGIN: POSITIVE NEGATIVE NECROSIS: PRESENT ABSENT SERUM TUMOR MARKERS: AVAILABLE NOT AVAILABLE PT**NXMXSX (AJCC 2010, SEVENTH EDITION) Appropriately controlled immunohistochemical stains for PLAP, OCT3/4, CD30, C-kit, and Pan cytokeratin were performed on a select representative block **# with following results: PLAP positive, OCT 3/4 positive, CD30 Negative, C-kit positive and Pan cytokeratin negative, supporting the above diagnosis.";
    String str=value;
    if (value.contains("*")) {
        value = value.replace("*", "[\\s\\S]*");
    }
    if (str.trim().matches(value)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    }else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: "A lot of"  is not a unit of time, specify it. Also why did tagged the question with all the languages you can.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but no matter how long it takes (I stopped the test after a minute) you result will `false` because your string contains `...(ITGN)...`, which matches not itself but `...ITGN...` and stores it in a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

What makes it so slow is that your string contains `**` which are replaced with two matches for anything with an unlimited quantifier.

Replace

```
value = value.replace("*", "[\\s\\S]*");
```

with

```
value = value.replace("**", "*").replace("*", "[\\s\\S]*");
```

and you get your result much faster.

---

Please beware that

```
String value="SOME (A) OTHER";
System.out.println(value.matches(value));
```

will always print false - the regular expression `"SOME (A) OTHER"` doesn't match itself, it matches `"SOME A OTHER"`

Comment: after using this replace ** with * am getting false value.It execution is fast but the value is returning is incorrect.

Comment: The problem is with your test string. Specifically, the pattern `"(A)"` does not match the string `"(A)"`, it matches only `"A"`. And your string contains `"...(ITGN)..."` @naveen